# List manipulation in Tcl

Tags: tcl

I have a list which I am trying to modify and make a new list based on what I am trying to achieve.

Original List

```
$> set a {123.4:xyz 123.4:pqr 123.4:xyz 123.4:abc 123.4:mno}
$> puts $a
$> 123.4:xyz 123.4:pqr 123.4:xyz 123.4:abc 123.4:mno
```

I want my new list to contain following elements

```
$> puts $a
$> xyz pqr xyz abc mno
```

I tried `split $a :` but it did not work out for me. Please suggest what can be done.

Comment: So many good answers. Love Tcl!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By making use of split command:

```
set a { 123.4:xyz 123.4:pqr 123.4:xyz 123.4:abc 123.4 :mno }
set c [list]
foreach ele $a {
    lappend c [lindex [split $ele ":"] 1]
} 
puts $c
```

output : xyz pqr xyz abc mno

Answer (score 2):

If you've got Tcl 8.6:

```
set a [lmap x $x {regsub {^[^:]*:} $x ""}]
```

In 8.5, it's easier if you store in another variable:

```
set b {}
foreach x $a {
    lappend b [regsub {^[^:]*:} $x ""]
}
```

In 8.4 and before, you also need a slightly different syntax for `regsub`:

```
set b {}
foreach x $a {
    # Mandatory write back to a variable...
    regsub {^[^:]*:} $x "" x
    # Store the value; it isn't reflected back into the source list by [foreach]
    lappend b $x
}
```

Comment: There are other ways to do the colon-splitting; which is best depends on all sorts of factors, but REs are pretty flexible…

Comment: I have 8.4.6, so first solution rules out.

Comment: Second solution set b{}; foreach x $a { lappend b [regsub {^[^:]*:} $x ""] } Error: wrong # args: should be "regsub ?switches? exp string subSpec varName

Comment: @user2643899 Oh, for 8.4 a slightly different syntax is required; will update (and it really helps to mention the version in the question when it's a bit old…)

Comment: I need a slight modification to a list can you help

Answer (score 2):

```
set b [list]
foreach item $a {
    catch { 
        regexp {\:(.*)} $item match tail 
        lappend b $tail
    }
}
puts $b
```

It's possible to do above with split instead of regexp; I prefer regexp because you can extract arbitrary patterns this way.

Comment: need modification to original question

Answer (score 2):

One Liner:

```
% set a {123.4:xyz 123.4:pqr 123.4:xyz 123.4:abc 123.4:mno}
% 123.4:xyz 123.4:pqr 123.4:xyz 123.4:abc 123.4:mno
set b [regexp -inline -all {[a-z]+} $a]
% xyz pqr xyz abc mno
```

Taddaaaa... No split required, if you have regex.

Comment: I need slight modification to a list can you help

Comment: yup... Lets see i can help?

Answer (score 1):

```
set a {123.4:xyz 123.4:pqr 123.4:xyz 123.4:abc 123.4:mno}
for {set i 0} {$i < [llength $a]} {incr i} {
  lset a $i [lindex [split [lindex $a $i] ":"] 1]
}
puts $a
```

Comment: i thought of this but really wanted to avoid for loop

Comment: @user2643899 Why is avoiding a `for` loop so important that you rather double the amount of memory your script uses for the list by making a copy in a `foreach` loop? ;)

Comment: Can you please check for the slight modification that i have just posted to the question

Answer (score 0):

```
set input {123.4:xyz 123.4:pqr 123.4:xyz 123.4:abc 123.4:mno}
set a ""

for {set i 0} {$i<[llength $input]} {incr i} {

        set a "$a [string trim [lindex $input $i] {0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,.,:}]"
}
```

This will trim the input.

Comment: The final argument to `string trim` is a *set* of characters, so you should use `"0123456789.:"`. And why are you constructing a string for the output instead of building a list?

Comment: @glennjackman The output you will obtain will be a list. I am just manipulating each string in a list and again forming a list.We can use "0123456789.:" also producing the same result as {}.

Comment: @Karthik please check new modification i requested

Answer (score 0):

If you have 8.5 and tcllib:

```
struct::list map $a {apply {{elem} {lindex [split $elem :] end}}}
```